# Rubocop installation (machine: linux-gnu, Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I go through the process of installing the rubocop `gem install rubocop --version 0.86.0`

And run `rubocop -v` afterwards to make sure everything is fine.
Instead, I receive the message below:

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby27, which recognizes
warning: 2.7.2-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.7.0.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
1.8.1
```

From what I can understand with my limited knowledge, it says that my ruby version is not compatible. Is that right? That I'm using 2.7.0 and I need to use 2.7.2 or above.

I run `rvm ls`

```
=* ruby-2.7.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

Then I try to run `ruby -v`

```
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I've gone through the process of `rvm install 2.7.2` & `rvm use 2.7.2` I have toggled-on 'Run command as a login shell' - because that was the only way I could get 'rvm' to work in the terminal.

If someone is able to help me with how I can upgrade my ruby version, it would be greatly appreciated.

Sidenote - I tried to follow the link  `https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri. 1.8.1` and I willingly admit I don't understand what's going on, on this page or how I can use it to solve the problem.

Lucas R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore this warning. The `parser` gem takes things very seriously; it is detecting that you are running a different patch version than it expects (2.7.2 instead of 2.7.0), but there are normally no syntax changes between patch versions.

Unrelated note: `rubocop` 0.86 is very old; you should upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thank you Marc-André. Its working despite the warning - good looking out. I'm using this particular version for a reason at the moment, I will definitely upgrade it in the future.